# Is it wrong to say "be reminding me in your prayers?"

Tags: imperative-sentences

Is it wrong to say "be reminding me in your prayers?"

Most often when we ask people to pray for us, they initially answer by saying they always pray for us. So I perceived such thoughts and asked someone that he should be reminding me in his prayers but he said I’m wrong. I tried searching for why I’m wrong but I’m not getting answers.

Comment: You could say "Please remember me in your prayers", but I don't see how the meaning would really differ from "Please pray for me".  If people generally answer the latter by saying that they always do so, they could respond to your request to remember you in exactly the same way.

Answer (score 3):

When you ask someone to remind you, you are asking them to say something to you so that you remember something.
[American Heritage Dictionary "remind"](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=remind)

> To cause to remember; put in mind:
> *must remind him to call; reminded her of college days.*

In your use, you are asking to be remembered by someone else. You aren't asking them to remind you about something.